# unmet dependencies when install ros-electric-desktop-full

Tags: ros, installation, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 10.04.
How to fix it?
Thank you~

My sources.list:

```
  # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20100816.1)]/       lucid main restricted
  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade       to
  # newer versions of the distribution.
  
  deb http://mirror.nttu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
  deb-src http://mirror.nttu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
  
  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
  ## distribution.
  
  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the       Ubuntu
  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  deb http://mirror.nttu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ lucid universe
  deb-src http://mirror.nttu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ lucid universe
  
  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the       Ubuntu 
  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
  ## security team.
  deb http://mirror.nttu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
  deb-src http://mirror.nttu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
  
  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
  ## repository.
  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  # deb http://mirror.nttu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted       universe multiverse
  # deb-src http://mirror.nttu.edu.tw/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted       universe multiverse
  
  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
  ## 'partner' repository.
  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
  
  deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian lucid non-free
  
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
```

----message----

```
  sam@sam-desktop:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo apt-get install       ros-electric-desktop-full
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
  The following information may help to resolve the situation:
  
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    ros-electric-desktop-full: Depends: ros-electric-ros-tutorials (=       0.2.6-s1320569927~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-geometry-tutorials (=       0.1.3-s1320570058~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-slam-gmapping (=       1.2.4-s1321937277~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-stage (=       1.4.1-s1320566684~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-visualization (=       1.6.7-s1321579535~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-vision-opencv (=       1.6.9-s1321926535~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-perception-pcl (=       1.0.2-s1321921954~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends:       ros-electric-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.2-s1320565385~lucid) but it is not going       to be installed
                               Depends:       ros-electric-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1320578733~lucid) but it is not       going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-rx (=       1.6.1-s1320557484~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-image-pipeline (=       1.6.3-s1321933695~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-simulator-gazebo (=       1.4.9-s1321931428~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-diagnostics-monitors       (= 1.4.1-s1320564052~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-simulator-stage (=       1.4.0-s1320566819~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends:       ros-electric-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1320587331~lucid) but it is not going       to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-common-tutorials (=       0.1.2-s1320587623~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends:       ros-electric-visualization-common (= 1.6.2-s1320557679~lucid) but it is not going to       be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-physics-ode (=       1.6.1-s1320556994~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-driver-common (=       1.2.4-s1320552073~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends:       ros-electric-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.2-s1321933589~lucid) but it is not going       to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-robot-model (=       1.6.3-s1320555147~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-bullet (=       2.76.5-s1320552187~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends:       ros-electric-visualization-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1321607759~lucid) but it is not going to       be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-geometry (=       1.6.1-s1320552445~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends:       ros-electric-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.2-s1320574185~lucid) but it is not       going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-laser-pipeline (=       1.2.0-s1320557286~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-electric-navigation (=       1.6.5-s1321934953~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
  E: Broken packages
  sam@sam-desktop:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12272/unmet-dependencies-when-install-ros-electric-desktop-full/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your source.list mixes lucid and maverick entries. You should only have lucid entries in a 10.04 installation. I would replace all maverick entries with the respective lucid entries, run apt-get update and hope that is enough.

In the case this doesn't work something on your system doesn't fit together anymore. What I would suggest is to follow the problem to the root, i.e.

- Try to install one of the packages (e.g. ros-electric-vision-opencv) manually/directly
- You should see more errors - follow the procedure until you hit a non-ROS package
- reinstall this package - you should now have the package installed that fits the rest of your system

You can always check what is going on with your package by using apt-cache policy, e.g.

```
libopencv2.3-dev:
  Installiert: 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-9~lucid
  Kandidat: 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-9~lucid
  Versions-Tabelle:
 *** 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-9~lucid 0
        500 http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/packages/ros/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This tells you which versions are available, what you have installed and what a candidate for installation would be. The versions should fit.
You especially have a problem if a package is installed in a newer version than available as it probably originated from maverick.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-12-08**:
I replace maverick to lucid, and start new terminal to try update & install. But the situation still the same.What to do next? (I have updated the original post)